# Websockets - not working in weblogic 12.2.1?

Tags: java, websocket, weblogic12c, atmosphere, java-websocket

Weblogic - 12.2.1 - not initializing the ServerContainer !

Hello Everyone ,
I am facing an issue while starting my application on weblogic 12.2.1 , as per the websocket spec i am initializing the websocket end-point at the time of startup of application in ServletContextListener . I am using atmosphere framework to start the websocket endpoint.  While initializing the socket endpoint in class JSR356AsyncSupport - atmosphere framework tries to fetch the attribute from servletContext object . It doesn't find it and fails .... in weblogic 12.2.1 / 12.1.3. However the same application when deployed on other web/appservers like tomcat , websphere liberty , jboss works fine. (Am using jdk1.8)

(https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/master/modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/container/JSR356AsyncSuppo… )

I don't have clue how to solve this - Much Appreciated if some one can help me out. Thank you.

```
public JSR356AsyncSupport(AtmosphereConfig config, ServletContext ctx) {
    super(config);
    ServerContainer container = (ServerContainer) ctx.getAttribute(ServerContainer.class.getName()); //javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer


    if (container == null) {
        if (ctx.getServerInfo().contains("WebLogic")) {
            logger.error("{} must use JDK 1.8+ with WebSocket", ctx.getServerInfo());
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null");
    }
}
```

Exception stack trace.

```
2016-08-16 16:10:31,459 [            WGHALBW7] [  STANDARD] [ ] [ ] (pr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver) ERROR   - Real error: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null
at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:51)
at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:235)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:307)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:293)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:2004)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:911)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:835)
```

Comment: Have you read the weblogic docs? https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG807

Comment: thank you for sharing the documentation , my application works perfectly alright on websphere liberty.jboss , tomcat . however it doesn't work on weblogic..  I went through the documentation - not much help for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to the party, but I'm currently working with weblogic 12.1.3 and though it does implement the websocket protocol ([oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG805), [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)), unfortunately it [does not comply](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) with [JSR356](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) (only from version 12.2.1 and up).

If you are using atmosphere, I've managed to configure a more-or-less working example by fine-tuning some of the atmosphere/primefaces servlet (I'm using Primefaces 6.0 *socket* for the server notifications) init-params:

```
<servlet>
    <description>PrimeFaces Push Notifications Servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.project.push</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.atmosphereHandlerPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.resumeOnBroadcast</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.suppressJSR356</param-name> <!-- les versions que tenim no son JSR356-compliant -->
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor.clientHeartbeatFrequencyInSeconds</param-name>
        <param-value>20</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Anyway, it's being really hard to implement and I'm considering other options.

More info [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1856) and [here](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/5547).